# Android: Intent restarts activity instead of directing to the main one

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my app, we have an EnterPin activity that gets the pin saved in the SharedPreference and compares it to what you entered. If it is correct, an intent brings you to the MainActivity and passes a true boolean with the key "verified"

For some reason, on both the emulator and my s7, after entering correct pin (Confirmed with debugging), it just restarts the EnterPinActivity.

The MOST annoying part is that it sometimes works and sometimes does not. I don't understand what could be causing this issue.

EnterPin.java

```
public class EnterPin extends AppCompatActivity {
//Used to check if there is a pin
SharedPreferences preferences;

//Title of the private file for the pin
public final String PINFILE = "PinFile";

private int pin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_pin);

    pin = getPinFromFile();

    //TODO::add similar check for security questions in case they exit the app during creation
    //If the user did not create a pin, send to create one and end this activity
    if(pin == -1) {
        forceCreatePin();
        finish();
    }

    Button logBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.logBtn);
    Button forgotBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.forgotPin);
}

public void onClick(View v){
    if(v.getId() == R.id.logBtn){
        EditText pinIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterPin);
        String pinStr = pinIn.getText().toString();
        if (pinStr.length() == 4) {
            int pinInt = Integer.parseInt(pinStr);
            if (pin == pinInt) {
                //Login
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("verified", true);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                //clear input and notify user of wrong pin
                pinIn.setText("");
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect PIN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        } else {
            pinIn.setText("");
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PIN must be 4 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }else if(v.getId() == R.id.forgotPin){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ForgotPIN.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

}

private int getPinFromFile() {
    preferences = getSharedPreferences(PINFILE, MODE_PRIVATE);
    //Returns value at key "pin" if it exists, -1 if pin is not created
    return preferences.getInt(PINFILE, -1);
}

private void forceCreatePin() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreatePin.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //get verified key from intent activity was started with, set false if key not found
    isVerified = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("verified", false);
    if (!isVerified) {
        forceEnterPin();
    }

 //We create the db in the main class
 try {
     db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("budgetDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
     System.out.println("Succes!!!!!!!");

 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
     System.out.println("It got caught....");
     Log.e("BudgetDatabase ERROR", "Error Creating/Loading database");
 }
    Database budDB = new Database(db);
    budDB.createTables();


    //Loading variables, settings the first fragment to the home screen
    spendableInc = loadSpendableInc();
    FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    trans.add(R.id.frag_container, homeFragment, "home").commit();


    //Settings functionality for the bottom navigation bar
    final FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frag_container);
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        //Handling clicks on home, transaction, or overview
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_home:
                HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                transaction.replace(R.id.frag_container, homeFragment, "home").commit();
                break;
            case R.id.action_transactions:
                TransactionFragment transactionFragment = new TransactionFragment();
                transaction.replace(R.id.frag_container, transactionFragment, "transaction").commit();
                break;
            case R.id.action_overview:
                OverviewFragment overviewFragment = new OverviewFragment();
                transaction.replace(R.id.frag_container, overviewFragment, "overview").commit();
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});

}

/**
 * Auto-generated method for toolbar
 * @param menu
 * @return
 */
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Auto-generated method for toolbar
 * @param item
 * @return
 */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.logout) {
        forceEnterPin();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public void saveSpendableInc(float amt) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(SPENDABLE_INCOME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putFloat(SPENDABLE_INCOME, amt);
    editor.commit();
}

public float loadSpendableInc() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SPENDABLE_INCOME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return prefs.getFloat(SPENDABLE_INCOME, MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public void createIncome(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateIncome.class);
    intent.putExtra(SPENDABLE_INCOME, spendableInc);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void createExpense(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateExpense.class);
    intent.putExtra(SPENDABLE_INCOME, spendableInc);
    startActivity(intent);
}

/**
 * Closes the database when the application is terminated
 * Set verified to false to force
 */
@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    db.close();
    getIntent().putExtra("verified", false);
    idleStart = 0;
    idleFinish = 0;
}

//Forces user to create pin and ends the main activity so the user can't use the back button to get to home screen
private void forceEnterPin() {
    getIntent().putExtra("verified", false);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EnterPin.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    //finish();
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    Calendar tmpCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    idleStart = tmpCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    Calendar tmpCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    //If app went straight to stop phase, start at 0
    //If app started at pause and then went to stop, add time from before
    if(idleStart == 0)
        idleStart = tmpCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    else
        idleStart += tmpCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    //Use calendar object to get the current time in minutes
    Calendar tmpCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    idleFinish = tmpCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    if(idleFinish - idleStart >= 30)
        forceEnterPin();

    //Reset idle times because user started app again
    idleStart = 0;
    idleFinish = 0;
}
}
```

Comment: in forceEnterPin(), why you have commented out the finish?I guess you have some trouble with getting verified from the intent. Try to finish MainActivity after starting another one....

Comment: It was initially not commented, that was just for testing. The error occurs in both,

Comment: I haven´t seen it yesterday, but now: in OnDestroy() you are put the verified intent, remove this. onDestroy() is usually called if you finish your activity. It´s not guaranteed to be called like stated out in the api. I guess that´s the problem, why it sometimes works and sometimes not.

Comment: I've actually figured it out-- I feel really dumb. I had added a feature that (should) time you out after 30 minutes, but the calendar API I used gave the actual minute of the hour rather than a timestamp. So it turns out you were unable to use the app after the 30 minute mark of any hour.


*sigh*

Answer (score -1):

Answer: Read the API you use first before you make it start an activity for you.